# WM_DPICHANGE message not received

Tags: windows, delphi, dpi

I'm using Delphi XE7 to test the issues around making an application DPI aware.

One of the tasks is to respond to the WM_DPICHANGE message which should get generated when a window is moved to a monitor with a different DPI value. I don't have a multi monitor set up so I wrote a very simple test program that generates this message, but it is not received on a windows 8.1 platform. It works OK on Windows 7. The following program demonstrates this:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

const
   WM_DPICHANGED = 736;  // 0x02E0

type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure DPIChanged(var Message: TMessage); message WM_DPICHANGED;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MyForm: TMyForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   PostMessage(Self.Handle,WM_DPICHANGED,0,0);
end;

procedure TMyForm.DPIChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
   ShowMessage('Message WM_DPICHANGED Received');
end;

end.
```

The ShowMessage does not appear when run under Windows 8.1. Is something eating the message before it hits my program?

Comment: You have no chance whatsoever of achieving anything without multiple monitors

Comment: This will accomplish nothing. Even if you could catch the message, there's no way you can test how you respond to it without having a second monitor with a different DPI setting. It's like trying to write an Android app without having an Android device or simulator; anything you do is simple guesswork and bound to fail.

Comment: Also, you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn312083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where it says that this message will only be received by applications that have registered to be `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE`, right?

Answer (score 3):

`WM_DPICHANGED` is supported only on Windows 8.1 and newer.

When you say that your code works on Windows 7, it actually works in a way that clicking on button posts message to your window and you are capturing that message. On the other hand it has nothing to do with actual DPI changing. On Windows 7 `WM_DPICHANGED` is treated just like you have sent some custom message.

On Windows 8.1 and newer `WM_DPICHANGED` is Windows API defined message. Sending that message using `PostMessage` fails with error code `1159 ERROR_MESSAGE_SYNC_ONLY`

That error means that you cannot send that particular message asynchronously. Problem here is in second parameter here that is pointer to `RECT` structure in case of `WM_DPICHANGED` message as defined in Windows API.

[WM_DPICHANGED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn312083(v=vs.85).aspx)

> - *wParam* - The HIWORD of the wParam contains the Y-axis value of the new dpi of the window. The LOWORD of the wParam contains the
>     X-axis value of the new DPI of the window. For example, 96, 120, 144,
>     or 192. The values of the X-axis and the Y-axis are identical for
>     Windows apps.
> - *lParam* - A **pointer** to a RECT structure that provides a suggested size and position of the current window scaled for the new
>     DPI. The expectation is that apps will reposition and resize windows
>     based on the suggestions provided by lParam when handling this
>     message.

[PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944.aspx)

> If you send a message in the range below WM_USER to the asynchronous
>   message functions (PostMessage, SendNotifyMessage, and
>   SendMessageCallback), its message parameters cannot include pointers.
>   Otherwise, the operation will fail. The functions will return before
>   the receiving thread has had a chance to process the message and the
>   sender will free the memory before it is used.

If you change `PostMessage` in your code to `SendMessage` your button click will work on Windows 8.1+, too.

Of course, if you have properly set up your application DPI awareness it will  normally process `WM_DPICHANGED` messages sent by Windows, too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was worried that my window (which was DPI aware with a manifest) wasn't getting the message because it was something Delphi was doing. I just need to get myself a multi-monitor test platform now.

Comment: *"Windows is protecting that queue from receiving WM_DPICHANGED messages that are not directly sent by system."* Looks suspicious to me, *sent* messages don't even end up in queue. Watching for messages that normally never appear in a queue would be a waste of resources. However I can't test/verify anything...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I made that comment for `PostMessage` where messages are sent to message queue. And it is obvious that they are not passed on to window as expected. what exactly and why is happening I don't know and you would mostly likely have to be MS developer to know exact details. `SendMessage` behaves differently as I have written.

Comment: @Dalija did you check the return of PostMessage?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz No, I didn't. thanks for reminding me. That brings whole new explanation in the picture. Current one falls into early morning (or not so early) idiocy.  I will update answer shortly.